# Remove ID page from wp_count

Tags: pages, count, exclude

I'm try to create a pages counter excluding certain ID pages but the code don't work.

I'm using this code. How can I fix it? Thanks.

```
<?php
$count_pages = wp_count_posts('page');
echo "$count_pages->publish";
$args = array(
    'post__not_in' => array(10010),
     );
    query_posts($args);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you to exclude via ID:

```
//replace the 3,8 with your page ids
<?php  $args=array(
  'post__not_in' => array(3,8),
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
); 
query_posts($args); ?>
```

If you want to exclude via page title you can do this

```
<?php $exclude1 = get_page_by_title('Sample Page Title'); ?>
<?php $exclude2 = get_page_by_title('Sample Page Title 2'); ?>
<?php $args = array(    
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'post__not_in' => array($exclude1->ID,$exclude2->ID)
    );
    query_posts($args);  ?>
```

Comment: Thanks demo7up, but the first code display this error on my template:
Call to a member function is_on_sale() on null in /home/xxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/sale-flash.php

Comment: Did you add/change the page id's to your own?

Comment: Yes I did it :S
There's a blank space where the code would be displayed, and the error apears on the bottom of the page.

Comment: The error is from a plugin can you disable woocommerce and try again just to verify.